# Is the inequality 3≥2 mathematically true?

Tags: inequality

I know, it's obvious that 3>2. Just wanted to know that if someone writes this as 3≥2 what conclusion should we conclude ?

Comment: What makes you think it wouldn't be true?

Comment: $a\ge b$ means that either $a\gt b$ or $a=b$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By itself, "$3 \gt$ [[is greater than]] $2$" (strong true statement) and thus we can say "$3 \ge$ [[is greater than **OR** equal to]] $2$" (weak true statement) but not "3 [[is greater than **AND** equal to]] $2$" (false statement) which are all obvious.

Why "$3 \ge 2$" ? It is generally useful in some Proofs, which can be simplified by the **OR** criteria.
Here is one Example: We might start with $ A = \{2,3,4,5\} $ & $ B = \{1,2\} $ and claim that Every element $a$ of $A$ is greater than **OR** equal to Every element $b$ of $B$.
$$a \in A \ge b \in B$$
Here, it is true even when we take $a=3$ from $A$ and $b=2$ from $B$, where we get $3 \ge 2$.

Comment: Please use MathJax consistently.

Answer (score 1):

$3\geq 2$ should be interpreted as $ (3>2 )\vee (3=2)$. By the truth table of the $\vee$ conjunction, the statement is true if any of the two parts are true. Since $3>2$ is true, hence the whole statement is true.